# Cakephp 3 : How to fetch joing table associated data?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I have a table name `countries` , `countries` has relation with `users`, `users` has relation with `MoneyTransferTransactions`

In `MoneyTransferTransactions` view I need fetch country name.

I already join Users table in `MoneyTransferTransactionsTable` by below code

```
$this->belongsTo('Users', [
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
                'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

In user table I also used inner join like below code

```
$this->belongsTo('Countries', [
            'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

In MoneyTransferTransactions controller I have used below code to fetch all data with associated data.

```
$this->paginate = [
           'contain' => ['Users','TransferOptions'],
           'conditions'=> ['MoneyTransferTransactions.status'=>1],
           'order'  =>['MoneyTransferTransactions.id'=>'DESC']
];
```

I have used var_dump in index.ctp , I gotted country id from `users` table but not got country name from countries table. How can I get country name from `MoneyTransferTransactions>index.ctp` ?

Comment: You have to add Countries to contain

Comment: It given me error "MoneyTransferTransactions is not associated with Countries "

Comment: than add Users.Countries to contain and remove Users from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add association between Users and Countries in 'contain'

```
$this->paginate = [
    'contain' => ['TransferOptions', 'Users' => ['Countries']],
    'conditions' => ['MoneyTransferTransactions.status' => 1],
    'order' => ['MoneyTransferTransactions.id' => 'DESC']
];
```